# Can a single exception use case be associated with more than 1 use case?

Tags: uml

I'm doing a bit of UML modelling and came across a scenario where I have two use cases:

- Register User
- Register Admin

I was just wondering if I could have the same alternative flow for both use-cases, and if so, how would I do the notation for that use case? At the moment i have the same alternative flow associating with different IDs (1 per use case)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that

> "Alternative Flow" means  a flow which is triggered by a condition.In other words "not always executed".

Then you can use "extend" relationship in your diagram:

[image]

Comment: Though doesn't an extend continue with the main flow afterwards. I thought the whole point of an exception like Cancel Registration is that it doesn't return to main flow?

Comment: Maybe i give a bad name.Cancel Registration is not an "exception" like in a programming language.Cancel Registration is just an alternative path. The main scenario can continue or not continue after alternative scenario "Cancel Registration"  based on how you write your main use case scenario.